# ¿Por que al asignar valor mediante PDO a OFFSET no funciona? PHP

Tags: php, sql, pdo

Estoy haciendo una consulta preparada, pero por alguna razón al insertar el valor de la variable mediante consulta preparada esta no funciona a diferencia si inserto directamente la variable, aquí el código:

Asi funciona:

```
public static function getfinishedproducts($offset) {
    $OFFSET = ($offset == "") ? 0 : $offset;
    $query = self::connect()->prepare("SELECT * FROM `finished_products` ORDER BY `id` LIMIT 5 OFFSET $OFFSET");
    $query->execute();
    return $row = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
}
```

Así no:

```
 public static function getfinishedproducts($offset) {
    $OFFSET = ($offset == "") ? 0 : $offset;
    $query = self::connect()->prepare("SELECT * FROM `finished_products` ORDER BY `id` LIMIT 5 OFFSET :offset");
    $query->execute(["offset"=>$OFFSET]);
    return $row = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Te falta agregar `:` a la clave del arreglo que le pasas al `execute`, es decir:

```
//...
$query = self::connect()->prepare("SELECT * FROM `finished_products` ORDER BY `id` LIMIT 5 OFFSET :offset");
// Aca: agregar ":" a la clave
$query->execute([":offset" => $OFFSET]);
//...
```

Comment: no funciona tampoco

Comment: ¿No funciona la consulta o no devuelve el resultado esperado? Son dos cosas distintas, siendo el segundo OTRO problema.